# why my handler cant detect changing data attribute <aura:attribute name="soqlRequestString" type="String" access="global"/> passed from MainComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx

### ElectronicCigaretteTableComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="ProductController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

        <aura:attribute name="soqlRequestString" type="String" access="global"/>
        <aura:attribute name="listProducts" type="List" />
        <aura:attribute name="offset" type="Integer" default="0" />
        <aura:attribute name="allProductSOQL" type="String" default=" SELECT Name,AirRegulator__c,AmountReview__c,BatteryCapacity__c,ChargingTime__c,Length__c,NumberUnits__c,Rating__c,TankSize__c,(SELECT Product2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntries) FROM Product2 LIMIT 4 " />


        <aura:handler name="updateSOQLRequest" value="{!v.soqlRequestString}" action="{!c.updateSOQLRequestHandler}"  />
        <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
        <aura:handler name="selectedSomeSort" event="c:sendSOQLRequestStringEvent" action="{!c.handlSeselectedSomeSortEvent}" /> 



        <div class="slds-scrollable" aura:id="scrollContainer">
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="layoutClass">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.listProducts}" var="itemProduct">
                    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="12" smallDeviceSize="6" mediumDeviceSize="6" class="layoutItemClass">
                        <c:ElectronicCigaretteCardComponent product="{!itemProduct}"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:layout>
        </div>
    </aura:component>
```

### ElectronicCigaretteTableComponentController.js

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.ProductInfo(component);
    },

    handlSeselectedSomeSortEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('updateSOQLRequestHandler: ');
        let updatedsoqlRequest = event.getParam("soqlRequest");
        alert('handlSeselectedSomeSortEvent: '+updatedsoqlRequest);
        component.set("v.offset",0);
        let zero=[];
        componen.set("v.listProducts",zero);
        helper.ProductInfo(component);  
    }
```

### MainComponentController.js

```
 handleclickCardEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        let product = event.getParam("product");
        let price = event.getParam("price");
        alert(product);
        component.set("v.productFromEvent",product);
        component.set("v.priceFromEvent",price);
    },
    handlSeselectedSomeSortEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        // let soqlRequest = component.get("v.soqlRequest");
        let updatedsoqlRequest = event.getParam("soqlRequest");
        alert('handlSeselectedSomeSortEvent: '+updatedsoqlRequest);
        // soqlRequest.push(updatedsoqlRequest);
        component.set("v.soqlRequest",updatedsoqlRequest);
    }
```

### MainComponent.cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="productFromEvent" type="Product2"  />
<aura:attribute name="priceFromEvent" type="String" default="optionalDefault" />
<aura:attribute name="soqlRequest" type="String"  default="optionalDefault" access="global"/>

<aura:handler name="clickCardEvent" event="c:sendElectronicCigaretteInfoEvent" action="{!c.handleclickCardEvent}" />
<!-- <aura:handler name="selectedSomeSort" event="c:sendSOQLRequestStringEvent" action="{!c.handlSeselectedSomeSortEvent}" />  -->


 <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center" multipleRows="false" class="mainContainer">
    <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="3">
        <c:ElectronicCigaretteSortComponent/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
        <c:ElectronicCigaretteTableComponent soqlRequestString="{!v.soqlRequest}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="3">
        <c:ElectronicCigaretteInfoComponent product="{!v.productFromEvent}" price="{!v.priceFromEvent}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture changes to an attribute, use the [`aura:valueChange`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueChange/documentation) handler, whose name is "change":

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.soqlRequestString}" action="{!c.updateSOQLRequestHandler}"  />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.